# Filament 3 - Dynamic fields based on a select option with Tabs

Tags: laravel-filament, filamentphp

My problem is as follows

On the create page, when I select a product type on the "Default TAB" tab, the form associated with that product type should load on the "Data TAB" tab.

This works on the create page, the data is entered insert the database. However, when I open the editing page, even though the product type is loaded back from the database, the "Data TAB" on the second tab remains empty – the corresponding form is not loaded. Nothing is loaded.

What could be the solution?

```php
Tab::make('Default TAB')
    ->schema([
        Select::make('type_id')->label(__('Product Type'))->required()->searchable()
        ->options(\App\Models\List\ProductType::orderBy('id', 'asc')->pluck('name', 'id')->toArray())
        ->live(),
    ])->columns(4),
     
Tab::make('Data TAB')
    ->schema(fn (Get $get): array => match ($get('type_id')) {
        default => [],
        '1' => [ProductDataContactLensForm::make('cldata')->columns(4)],
        '3' => [ProductDataSunGlassForm::make('sgdata')->columns(4)],
        '5' => [ProductDataSpectacleFrameForm::make('sfdata')->columns(4)],
    }),
```

Answer (score 3):

On the create page, you will get real-time value from the `type_id` input.

However, on the Edit page, you either need to set value or get value from the table and use it.

```php
Forms\Components\Tabs::make('Tabs')
    ->tabs([
        Tabs\Tab::make('Default TAB')
            ->schema([
                Select::make('type_id')->label(__('Product Type'))->required()->searchable()
                ->options(\App\Models\List\ProductType::orderBy('id', 'asc')->pluck('name', 'id')->toArray())
                ->live(),
            ])->columns(4),
             
        Tabs\Tab::make('Data TAB')
            ->schema(function (Get $get, Pages\EditUser $livewire, Model ?$record): array {
                # If the page is Edit and the record exists, then get type_id and use it in the match()
                # and for creating a page it will work as expected.
                $type_id = ( $livewire instanceof Pages\EditUser && $record ) ? $record->type_id : $get('type_id');

                return match ($type_id) {
                    default => [],
                    '1' => [ProductDataContactLensForm::make('cldata')->columns(4)],
                    '3' => [ProductDataSunGlassForm::make('sgdata')->columns(4)],
                    '5' => [ProductDataSpectacleFrameForm::make('sfdata')->columns(4)],
                }
            }),
    ]),
```

Answer (score 0):

Improved

```
Tabs\Tab::make('Data TAB')
    ->schema(function (Get $get, Pages\EditProduct $livewire, ?Model $record): array {
        # If the page is Edit and the record exists, then get type_id and use it in the match()
        # and for creating a page it will work as expected.
        $type_id = ( $livewire instanceof Pages\EditProduct && $record ) ? $record->type_id : $get('type_id');

        return match ($type_id) {
            default => [],
            '1' => [ProductDataContactLensForm::make('cldata')->columns(4)],
            '3' => [ProductDataSunGlassForm::make('sgdata')->columns(4)],
            '5' => [ProductDataSpectacleFrameForm::make('sfdata')->columns(4)],
        };
    }),
```

Comment: you can upVote on my answer, instead of post answer from mine.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Its only work for edit page but when you go to create page then you got a error.So here is the both case solution.

```
   ->schema(function (Get $get, $livewire, ?Model $record): array {
            if ($livewire instanceof Pages\EditProduct) {
                // Handle EditProduct logic here
                $type_id = $record->type_id ?? '';
            } elseif ($livewire instanceof Pages\CreateProduct) {
                // Handle CreateProduct logic here
                $type_id = $get('type_id') ?? '';
            } else {
                // Handle other cases or raise an error as needed
                throw new \InvalidArgumentException('Unsupported $livewire instance.');
            }
            return match ($type_id) {
                default => [],
                '1' => [ProductDataContactLensForm::make('cldata')->columns(4)],
                '3' => [ProductDataSunGlassForm::make('sgdata')->columns(4)],
                '5' => [ProductDataSpectacleFrameForm::make('sfdata')->columns(4)],
            };
        })
```