# How to fill related fields when selecting an options in Laravel Filament?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-filament, filamentphp

I'm developing a system using Laravel and Filament where i have a Work Order form that creates an work order for certain devices.

I have already define the WorkOrder model and Device model using belongsTo in WorkOrder model.

I wanted to fill the related fields to the device i selected. How to achieve it? Here is my code :

```
                    Select::make('device_id')
                    ->relationship('device', 'name')
                    ->label(__('Device'))
                    ->searchable()
                    ->preload()
                    ->reactive()
                    ->afterStateUpdated(function ($state, Set $set) {
                        // Access the related device using the relationship
                        $device = $this->record->device;

                        // Update the TextInput fields if a device is selected
                        if ($device) {
                            $set('device_locations', $device->locations);
                            $set('device_sn', $device->sn);
                            $set('device_type', $device->type);
                            $set('device_vendor', $device->vendor);
                        }
                    }),
                TextInput::make('device_locations'),
                TextInput::make('device_sn'),
                TextInput::make('device_type'),
                TextInput::make('device_vendor')
```

The problem is when i'm using above code, there is a `$this can not be used in static methods` error. How is the work around for this?

Comment: Have you solved it? How did you access the selected device model inside the  afterStateUpdated()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the issue is with $this it is an instance of form object while you are using the form object too so it it not the way to solve the issue.

Check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77655908/filament-3-dynamic-fields-based-on-a-select-option-with-tabs) it may be useful.